# Can WPF control play YUV420P video with better performance?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video

i have a WPF windows application, i want play about 10 video from other live cam.

so the SDK provide the YUV420P, but the WPF don't play it at all.

so my solution is :

1. Convert YUV420P to BGRA byte[] on C#

```
private static void SetFramePixel(ClrVideoFrame frame, int positionX, int positionY, VideoChannelWrap data)
        {
            var y = frame.ybuffer[positionX + positionY * frame.yStride];
            var u = frame.ubuffer[(positionX >> 1) + (positionY >> 1) * frame.uStride];
            var v = frame.vbuffer[(positionX >> 1) + (positionY >> 1) * frame.vStride];
            var r = (int)(y + Rv * (v - Minus));
            var g = (int)(y - Gu * (u - Minus) - Gv * (v - Minus));
            var b = (int)(y + Bu * (u - Minus));
            r = CorrectOutOfRangeValue(r);
            g = CorrectOutOfRangeValue(g);
            b = CorrectOutOfRangeValue(b);
            // ReSharper disable once InconsistentlySynchronizedField
            data.data[positionX * BytesPerPixel + positionY * frame.yStride * BytesPerPixel] = (byte)b;
            // ReSharper disable once InconsistentlySynchronizedField
            data.data[positionX * BytesPerPixel + positionY * frame.yStride * BytesPerPixel + 1] = (byte)g;
            // ReSharper disable once InconsistentlySynchronizedField
            data.data[positionX * BytesPerPixel + positionY * frame.yStride * BytesPerPixel + 2] = (byte)r;
            // ReSharper disable once InconsistentlySynchronizedField
            data.data[positionX * BytesPerPixel + positionY * frame.yStride * BytesPerPixel + 3] = Max;
        }
```

2. WriteableBitmap update Image control

`Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, bitmap.BackBuffer, bytes.Length);`

but, the performance is bad, if the video is high 720P, the application don't use at all.

so, any new solution to play YUV420P video more good performance, or directly?

Comment: It will depend on the graphics card in your machine.  The resolution is only as good as the card and cannot be made better.

Comment: Processing video in real-time in managed code is a bad idea, you will never reach good performance with that. Consider using e.g. DirectShow to build a playback/streaming graph instead of manually processing the frames.

Comment: @dymanoid you are right c# will never be as fast as c++, BUT with unsafe pointers/stackalloc/hidden keywords you can get acceptable results.

Answer (score 0):

thanks.

i have test 4 types:

#### Solution 1：C#'s task coding.

tasksCount = 20ms

> ```
> DisplayVideo:1
> SetPixel:34
> DisplayVideo:1
> SetPixel:39
> DisplayVideo:1
> ```

```
**Release: (X64)**
SetPixel:11
DisplayVideo:2
SetPixel:10
DisplayVideo:2
```

#### solution 2：unsafe

DisplayVideo:30ms

#### solution 3：C++ wrap SetPixel

```
SetPixel_ClrVideoBGRA32Frame:26
DisplayVideo:2
SetPixel_ClrVideoBGRA32Frame:26
DisplayVideo:2
```

#### solution 4: C++ wrap ClrVideoBGRA32_SetFramePixel

```
SetPixel:73
DisplayVideo:1
SetPixel:61
DisplayVideo:1
```